# Load HTML files with Karma

Tags: node.js, testing, karma-runner

I'm using [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html) to test my client side codes done with JavaScript. So I have one html file which I want to load and then I want to get all elements from that html page in my test script.

Below is the `karma.conf.js` page code through which I am loading all my pages.

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
    'node_modules/karma-jstd-adapter/jstd-adapter.js',
    'testSetup.js',
    'config.js',
    'jquery.js',
    'test.htm',
    'startup.test.js'
];
```

There is 'DIV' having id `test` in test.htm. I am dynamically adding content to that `DIV`. So I need to verify that, I want to fetch the element content, but I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 7):

**You can use [html2js  preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor)**, which basically converts HTML files into JavaScript strings and include these files.

Then, you can access these strings in your test:

```
var elm = $(window.__html__['test.htm']);
```

Comment: I'm curious whether there is a specific reason to use this approach as opposed to document.open/write/close as shown here: https://gist.github.com/ssimeonov/8778619 Would this somehow "break" the Karma/Jasmine hookup in the browser?