# Test function in angular controller that uses the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, jasmine

we have an AngularJS controller that defines this function:

```
$scope.testMe = function() {
    return $('#test');
}
```

Now how can we test it?

Our try was a Karma test like this:

```
    describe('testMe', function() {
        var scope, element, ctrl;
        var html = '<span id="test"></span>';

        beforeEach(module('theModule'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('theCtrl', {$scope: scope});
            element = $compile(html)(scope);
        }));

        it('finds it', function() {
            var gotcha = scope.testMe();
            expect(gotcha.attr('id')).toBe('test');
        });
    });
```

...but it doesn't work - the jQuery seems to look in Karma's generated DOM, not in the DOM that we defined in `var html`...

Comment: Try to change `<span id="test"></span>` to `<span id="test" ng-controller="theCtrl"></span>`

Comment: Nope, that seems to spawn a second controller, but in its own scope. The init function of theCtrl gets called twice. 
If I then comment out the $controller line, the init function is run only once, and scope.testMe is not defined.
I can call element.scope().testMe() but it also doesn't return the DOM element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that appending the element you created into Karma's DOM will cause any problems.
You can do it like this:

```
$("body").append($compile(html)(scope));
scope.$digest();
```

If you don't want to mess with Karma's DOM perhaps try the [html2js preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor) suggested in this question: [Load HTML files with Karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317693/load-html-files-with-karma)